# How to call bootstrap's jQuery plugins in ES6

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6, webpack, html5boilerplate

I'm stuck trying to call the bootstrap's jQuery plugins, like popover, tooltip, modals, ...

I'm using webpack and this is my ES6 javascript:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
//import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap-sass';
//import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap-loader';
import Bootstrap from '../vendor/bootstrap.min.js';

class Test {
    constructor () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ html: true });
    }
}
```

I've tried to install bootstrap with npm, but after that i wasn't sure which one node-modules i had to import (like you can see in commented lines in the imports). So, i thought to import directly the `bootstrap.min.js`.

The fact is that i still have an error (independently if i try with popover/modals/tooltip) like this in my `app.js` that is my javascript generated from the webpack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).tooltip is not a function
```

Like i say, i'm stuck here.

Last thing, the boostrap CSS works correctly thanks to this:

```
gulp.task('bootstrap-fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/fonts/bootstrap'));
});

gulp.task('dev', ['css', 'bootstrap-fonts', 'browser-sync', 'webpack'], function () {
    gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['webpack']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', ['bs-reload']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the bootstrap library depends on jQuery,
you should try to add the following plugin to the 'plugins' array in your webpack.config.js so that the bootstrap module will use the jQuery global object:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": 'jquery'
}),
```

This plugin will actually injects the 'jquery' module in any other module that ask for him (means, every module that use the objects jQuery or $ or window.jQuery), and bootstrap is one of them.

Comment: It's not enough `import $ from 'jquery'` ?

Comment: No, because you just imported 'jquery' inside this current file (this current module) so only this file "knows" what is 'jquery' right now. but bootstrap himself is using the global jQuery object. And this is the webpack's way to let bootstrap know about the jQuery object

Comment: @Jumpa is this the same for other libraries as well? Let's say I have 2 components that need `library.js`. Do you think putting it in the global scope is a good practice than importing it twice (once on each component)?

Comment: @JohnnyQ It's not the same. In your case, I would import the library.js module twice (in every module that needs him). I talked about 3rd party libraries that relies on another 3rd party library (actually relies on a global object like bootstrap that relies on jQuery)

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why importing modules multiple times is better than importing is globally?

Comment: @JohnnyQ If we are using webpack, we actually need to embrace the module system (and not relay on globals. of course except the cases that we must), but maybe its just me :)